# Prove that $A_{5 \times 5}$ is a diagonalizable if $\operatorname{rank}(I+A)=\operatorname{rank}(2I-A)=3$ and $\det A=12$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation, diagonalization

> Prove that $A_{5 \times 5}$ is a diagonalizable if $\operatorname{rank}(I+A)=\operatorname{rank}(2I-A)=3$ and $\det A=12$.

Because $\operatorname{rank}(I+A)=\operatorname{rank}(2I-A)<5$ then:
$$
\det (I+A)=\det (2I-A)=0
$$
therefore there're two eigenvalues: $t_1=-1, t_2=2$.

We know that geometric multiplicity of $I+A$ is $n-\operatorname{rank}(I+A)=2$ likewise for $2I-A$.

Because the algebraic multiplicity is greater than or equal to the geometric and $\deg p(t)=5$, the characteristic polynomial is:
$$
p(t)=(t+1)^2(t-2)^2(t-x)
$$

Because $\det A=12$ this means that the free variable of $p(t)$ is $-12$.

I understand everything up until **this** point: because the free variable is $-12$ then:
$$
1\cdot 2^2\cdot (-x)=-12 \Rightarrow x=3 \quad (\ast)
$$
How do we get the equation $(\ast)$?

Comment: Shouldnt we have x=-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** You already know the free variable of the polynomial $p(t)$. What is the free variable of $(t+1)^2(t-2)^2(t-x)$?

Comment: After thinking about this I guess we can we get the free variable of $p(t)$ by simply multiplying between the "sub-variables" which are $1, -2, -x$. So the equation $(\ast)$ is essentially $1^2\cdot (-2)^2\cdot (-x)=-12\Rightarrow -4x=-12\Rightarrow x=3$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Could you clarify what you mean by "free variable of $p(t)$"? I assumed you meant "constant term", or in other words $p(0)$, but maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes I meant the constant term

Comment: Then yes, the constant term of the product $(t+1)^2(t-2)^2(t-x)$ is the product of the constant terms. So your equation $(*)$ just reflects the two ways to obtain the constant term of the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial is $p(t)=\det(tI-A)$. Therefore the constant term in $p$ is $p(0)=\det(-A)$. As the size of $A$ is odd, $\det(-A)=-\det A=-12$.

In general, if $A$ is $n\times n$, the constant term in the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(-1)^n\det(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

From the ranks you've found the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-1,\lambda_2=2$ have geometric multiplicity of 2,since the algebraic multiplicity is greater than or equal to the geometric multiplicity you know that $\lambda_1=-1,\lambda_2=2$ have at least algebraic multiplicity of $2$. But you've also got that 
 $detA=\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\lambda_4\lambda_5$ from there you have

$12=\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\lambda_4\lambda_5$

Where $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=-1$ and $\lambda_3=\lambda_4=2$.

$12=(-1)^22^2\lambda_5 \rightarrow \lambda_5=\frac{12}{4}=3$

Comment: what do you mean by $\det A=\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\lambda_4\lambda_5$? we have at most 3 potential eigenvalues why do you have 5 different indices?

Comment: determinant of a matrix is equal to their coresponding eigenvalues.
Since $A$ is a $5x5$ matrix it has 5 eigenvalues (they don't have to be different though),and from the information that you gave us we know that $detA=12$ so the product of all the eigenvalues for matrix A is equal to $12$.

And to correct your comment. We have at most 3 **different** eigenvalues